# IE Question: How many CSS includes can it handle?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser

I came across a strange behavior while theming Drupal. I turned a few modules that added 5 to 10 link tags to the page. While these new stylesheets were added to the cascade in Firefox, in IE8, by adding these the browser discarded the earlier added CSS files from the hierarchy. In fact, the first files were the first to go, which completely screwed up the styling of the page and had me scratching my head for a while. Eventually I discovered the newly added modules had caused IE to pass some internal threshold where it could not add new includes anymore.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? I'm not sure if it's an issue with browser or with my setup.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Internet Explorer has a maximum limit of 32 CSS file links.  Definitely a browser issue.  You'll need to think about consolidating your css requests.

Generally you can do this by concatenating them if they're static files, but if you're generating them programatically, you might have to look at a solution to manipulate the response before it gets passed to the browser.

We had to get around this issue for our enterprise ASP.Net project and ended up writing a "Css Multiplexor" that examined the response, found the requested CSS links, generated a web resource for one big css file, and output a link to that instead.

Comment: Drupal can do that natively, already. This can be found in Administer > Site configuration > Performance.

Comment: nice.  .Net 3.5 added this ability to some degree as well.

Comment: Uggggg - The limit is 31 CSS file links.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue on our site.

IE8 only permits 32 CSS imports per file. That file could be an HTML file or a CSS file. (*) However, the import limit does not restrict you to 32 CSS files total. You can link to two CSS files in your HTML, each of which @imports 32 CSS files. Playing with tricks like that should get you as many as you need.

The specific workaround we use is to split the CSS files we need into two groups, and have two 'import' CSS files. The HTML page imports the first import CSS file, which imports the first group and the second import CSS file, which imports the second group.

This works fine, but results in lots of HTTP requests, so we only use this workaround on development systems. For our live sites we have a build step that compiles all the CSS into one file.

What ***Johannes*** has mentioned -- getting Drupal to aggregate your CSS -- sounds like the best bet.

(*) There's some fine print like: the 32 imports includes the CSS files that have already been imported in the chain from your HTML page. So if your HTML imports a CSS file, then that CSS file can only import 31 other second-tier CSS files, and each second-tier CSS file can only import 30 other third-tier CSS files. You really have to wonder what bizarre algorithm causes this limitation...

Comment: Uggggg - The limit is 31 CSS file links. And an @import can only import 31 CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

**The limit is 31 - NOT 32!**

While some would say "who cares, close enough, right?" --- With larger applications with hundreds of developers it can be very easy for the page to go over the limit, so you should really know the exact number of css stylesheets can be included on the page.

There are several ways to mitigate the problem:

1. Reduce the number of CSS files by consolidating into larger files - perhaps manually, or some run time grouping mechanism, or you can use an automated css compiler to combine and minimize all your CSS files
2. Use `@import url(...)` statements rather than `<link href="">` but remember you can only have 31 `@import` (again, NOT 32...) statements in one stylesheet

**Use #2 above with caution because:**

1. You are only increasing the limit (to 961 css files) not removing it
2. The browser will be forced to download the CSS files in series rather than in parellel. Normally a browser can download more than 1 css file at a time (the count depends on if the files are in the same domain and which browser you are using) - This can have a significant impact on performance.
3. Each CSS file requires a round trip to the server adding extra time.