# can most mobile browsers cope with 3000 css style defintions?

Tags: css, styles, css-sprites, max

Using three thousand style definitions is highly unusual: is there a chance that some obscure mobile device might complain?

**Details:**
I'm creating a game to run on as many browsers as possible, so that means no using canvas. I tried animating characters by changing style variables, but that caused too many reflows. Next I tried changing DOM nodes all at once "innerHTML" and later tried replacechild and documentfragment. Most browsers are good, but Internet Explorer can't mess with DOM nodes for long periods without leaking memory (even IE9 leaks slowly). Every attempt at fixing one memory leak just caused another leak somewhere else. I finally used css instead, with a separate class for every pixel position. E.g.

```
class="Height123 Width456 Left789 Top0";
```

This runs quickly even on IE8, as it requires just one reflow, and has no memory leaks. It runs perfectly on every desktop browser I've tried, but it requires around three thousand classes. (I can't use any CSS3 shortcuts because IE8 only supports CSS2). That makes me nervous about smaller devices. I don't own every possible handheld, so I wonder if any of them are known to limit css styles?

Comment: If you didn't do this already, you could at least minify the names: class="H123 W456 L789 T0". Also limiting the classes to the actual device sizes would help. Your solution leaves me baffling.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, this was not my first solution, but it's the only one that seems to work. And yes, I have minified the style sheet and only use values that actually appear. But I'm using CSS sprites, which require negative numbers for offsetting purposes, so it's hard to get the number much below 3000.

Comment: Are you using JS directly or are you using a library like jQuery? And have you got examples of your code that is causing a memory leak? - What is your evidence for a leak? just because memory use goes up, doesent mean it wont go down later

Comment: JS directly. Sorry I don't have the code to hand - I'm on a friend's computer. I used "replacechild" repeatedly to change attributes of an img within a div. Evidence for a leak: It behaved nicely in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but on IE8 the memory use climbed from 200 MB to 1.3 gig and the computer froze. Many web sites report that IE6,7 and 8 don't release memory properly when updating the DOM. IE9 did the same, but much more slowly. I tried Douglas Crockford's "purge" code but it made no difference. I read several articles indicating that fixing one thing often caused problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is no size limit for css. 
Except that in MSIE can only support:

- 32 @import declaration ([IE Question: How many CSS includes can it handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082849/ie-question-how-many-css-includes-can-it-handle))
- 4095 repetition of the same selector (http://www.habdas.org/2010/05/30/msie-4095-selector-limit/)